# No class found error in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, noclassdeffounderror

I am using Netbeans 6.9 and sometimes when I try to run my projects in the Netbeans console it says,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ...<class name>
        at COMMON.FrmLogin.loging(FrmLogin.java:590)
        at COMMON.FrmLogin.chekuser(FrmLogin.java:520)
        at COMMON.FrmLogin.txtpwdKeyPressed(FrmLogin.java:448)
        at COMMON.FrmLogin.access$500(FrmLogin.java:15)
        at COMMON.FrmLogin$6.keyPressed(FrmLogin.java:217)
        at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6462)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2829)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
        at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1908)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:752)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1017)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:889)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:717)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4730)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Manufacturing.RepLedgerSummary
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 39 more
```

Though, the class mentioned in the error message is available, when that happens what I do is do some changes to the class mentioned in the error message and run the project again then it works and sometimes it says another class is not found as mentioned above. Please assist to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not set Class path of your project properly.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420613/netbeans-isnt-finding-my-class)